# How do I get this code to accommodate any given number by only using boolean logic (no conditionals/ functions)

Tags: python, boolean-logic, boolean-expression, boolean-operations

Here is the problem:

```
number = 1101
#You may modify the lines of code above, but don't move them!
#When you Submit your code, we'll change these lines to
#assign different values to the variables.
#
#The number above represents a binary number. It will always
#be up to eight digits, and all eight digits will always be
#either 1 or 0.
#
#The string gives the binary representation of a number. In
#binary, each digit of that string corresponds to a power of
#2. The far left digit represents 128, then 64, then 32, then
#16, then 8, then 4, then 2, and then finally 1 at the far right.
#
#So, to convert the number to a decimal number, you want to (for
#example) add 128 to the total if the first digit is 1, 64 if the
#second digit is 1, 32 if the third digit is 1, etc.
#
#For example, 00001101 is the number 13: there is a 0 in the 128s
#place, 64s place, 32s place, 16s place, and 2s place. There are
#1s in the 8s, 4s, and 1s place. 8 + 4 + 1 = 13.
#
#Note that although we use 'if' a lot to describe this problem,
#this can be done entirely boolean logic and numerical comparisons.
#
#Print the number that results from this conversion.
```

---

Here is my code

```
##Add your code here!

number_str = str(number) # "1101"
first_num = int(number_str[-1]) * 1
#print("first num:", first_num)
second_num = int(number_str[-2]) * 2
#print("second num:", second_num) 
third_num = int(number_str[-3]) * 4
#print("Third num:", third_num)
fourth_num = int(number_str[-4]) * 8
#print("fourth num:", fourth_num)
fifth_num = int(number_str[-5]) * 16
sixt_num = int(number_str[-6]) * 32
seventh_num = int(number_str[-7]) * 64
decimal = first_num + second_num + third_num + fourth_num + fifth_num + sixt_num + seventh_num
print(decimal)
```

The error I got was:
We found a few things wrong with your code. The first one is shown below, and the rest can be found in full_results.txt in the dropdown in the top left:
We tested your code with number = 1010111. We expected your code to print this:
87
However, it printed this:
7

---

I understand that I hard-coded this problem to accommodate 4 digits. I would like this to work for any given numbers without throwing an IndexError: string index out of range.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Your problem statement suggests using "numerical comparisons", which you do not do.  If you use numerical operations to isolate digits, your "string index" problem goes away.

Comment: All you need is a loop, to pull off the digits one by one.

Answer (score 3):

I don't like doing people's homework for them, but in this case I think the example says more than an explanation.

You do this conversion one character at a time, from left to right.  At each step, you shift the result left by one, and if the digit is '1', you add it in.

```
number = 1011
decimal = 0
for c in str(number):
    decimal = decimal * 2 + (c=='1')
print(decimal)
```

If that's too clever, replace `(c=='1')` with `int(c)`.

### FOLLOWUP

This is what I've been trying to tell you.  The code you have will actually do the correct conversion, but it only works if you have exactly 7 digits.  All you need to do is change the code so you CHECK the number of digits before you try one:

```
number = 1010111

num = str(number)
result = int(num[-1]) * 1
if len(num) > 1:
    result += int(num[-2]) * 2
if len(num) > 2:
    result += int(num[-3]) * 4
if len(num) > 3:
    result += int(num[-4]) * 8
if len(num) > 4:
    result += int(num[-5]) * 16
if len(num) > 5:
    result += int(num[-6]) * 32
if len(num) > 6:
    result += int(num[-7]) * 64
if len(num) > 7:
    result += int(num[-8]) * 128

print(result)
```

Comment: Hi Tim, Thanks for your reply. I am not allowed to use loops. How do I implement the same with numerical comparison?

Comment: You CANNOT handle an arbitrary number of digits without using a loop.  it's impossible.  Your second code snippet could be made to work by using `if len(number_str) > 4` before you try to access `number_str[-4]`, but that's not a good design.

Comment: That is the challenge I am facing. This problem is part of Georgia Tech's Intro to Programming first module. So far it covers just numerical expression and boolean logic. The next chapter is about control structure and functions, and so on. so, this problem should be solved by numerical comparisons.

Comment: The following is a problem where I converted number to binary:

number = 215


bin_128 = int(number >= 128)
bin_64 = int(number % 128 >= 64)
bin_32 = int(number % 64 >= 32)
bin_16 = int(number % 32 >= 16)
bin_8 = int(number % 16 >= 8)
bin_4 = int(number % 8 >= 4)
bin_2 = int(number % 4 >= 2)
bin_1 = int(number % 2 >= 1)

print(str(bin_128) + str(bin_64) + str(bin_32) + str(bin_16) + str(bin_8) + str(bin_4) + str(bin_2) + str(bin_1))

Now, I need to revise the process but my understanding is so limited.

Comment: Did you read what I wrote?  The code you have is fine, as long as you CHECK the length so you don't try to read digit `[-7]` when there aren't seven digits.  The output you show ("it printed this: 7") could not have been caused by the code you show.  That code would have produced the correct answer for 1010111, but would have failed with 1101 because of an index out of range error.

Comment: That's alright, Tim. The following code worked.

Comment: number = 1101

number_str =  "0000000" + str(number)  # "1101"
first_num = int(number_str[-1]) * 1
second_num = int(number_str[-2]) * 2
third_num = int(number_str[-3]) * 4
fourth_num = int(number_str[-4]) * 8

Comment: fifth_num = int(number_str[-5]) * 16
sixt_num = int(number_str[-6]) * 32
seventh_num = int(number_str[-7]) * 64
eighth_num = int(number_str[-8]) * 128
decimal = first_num + second_num + third_num + fourth_num + fifth_num + sixt_num + seventh_num + eighth_num
print(decimal)